# background image doesnt fill page width

Tags: html, css, background-image

I realize this is asked and answered in many ways, but after racking my brain, I can't figure out how to get it right. You can see that the background image doesnt fill the entire page (it stops shy by about 10px on both sides). Any advice?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottschaffer/bzzbxffr/1/)

CSS:

```
body {
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:22px;
    height: auto;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color:#122632;
    background-color:#afcbdc;
}
header {
    height: 57px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:14px;
    font-weight:300;
    z-index:99999;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#top-menu a:link {
    color: #122632;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.navWrapper {
    padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;
}
#top-menu {
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#top-menu li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#top-menu a {
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 14px 0px 14px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s all ease-out;
    transition: .5s all ease-out;
    color: #122632;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.bannerBkg {
    background-image:url("http://placehold.it/2000x610/333");
    background-position:top center;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 610px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index:999999;
    width:100%;
}
.bannerWrapper {
    width:94%;
    max-width:1200px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
#bannerRight {
    float:right;
    width:50%;
}
.bannerText {
    font-family:'Special Elite', cursive;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size:85px;
    line-height:75px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:right;
    width:46%;
    float:left;
    padding-top:155px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #132937;
}
.bannerTextSmall {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:30px;
    line-height:29px;
    padding-top:345px;
    text-align:right;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #132937;
}
#tentaclesHeader {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    left:50%;
    top:0px;
    z-index:99;
    background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/570/690/sports/");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top left;
    width:570px;
    height:690px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header class="nav-down">
    <div class="navWrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul id="top-menu">
                <li class="active"> <a href="#home">home</a>

                </li>
                <li>    <a href="#about">about</a>

                </li>
                <li>    <a href="#work">work</a>

                </li>
                <li>    <a href="#store">contact</a>

                </li>
                <li>    <a href="#resume" target="_blank">resume</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="bannerBkg">
    <div class="bannerWrapper">
        <div class="bannerText">test
            <br>copy
            <br> <span class="bannerTextSmall">blah blah blah</span>

        </div>
        <div id="tentaclesHeader"></div>
        <div id="bannerRight"></div>
        <div class="space"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `margin:0;` to your body tag css. body on most browsers has a default value of up to around 10px on the margins

```
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  height: auto;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  color: #122632;
  background-color: #afcbdc;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! i knew it would be something so simple that i was overlooking. i still have so much to learn.